# Cosets of $SO(2)$ in $SO(3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to know how to proof the cosets of $SO(2)$ in $SO(3)$ are the sets of matrices
$$
Q \ SO(2)=\{QR \ | \ R \in SO(2)\}，Q \in SO(3)
$$

Comment: Looks like the definition of coset.  What is there to prove?

Comment: If $Q \in SO(3)$, then order of matrix $Q$ is 3. If $R \in SO(2)$, then order of matrix $R$ is 2. How can they multiply with each other? And why $SO(2)$ is the subgroup of $SO(3)$? Thanks!

Comment: You have to agree on an embedding before you can regard it as a subgroup.  There is a standard way to do this.

Comment: Just add a column and row of 0,0,1.

Comment: I know the following fact that $$
R=
\left(
 \begin{matrix}
   \cos \theta & -\sin \theta\\
   \sin \theta & \cos \theta
 \end{matrix}
\right),\ \
Q=
\left(
 \begin{matrix}
   \cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0\\
   \sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 1
 \end{matrix}
\right)
$$

Comment: But how can they multiply with each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the $Q$ you have written in your comment is an element in $SO(3)$, that is not the form for a completely general element.  There are others.  An element of $SO(3)$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ satisyfing $A^t = A^{-1}$ and $\det(A)=1$.  If the matrix $A$ happens to be a rotation about the $z$-axis, it has the form you describe.  (Or, you must change your basis to put it in that form.)

Take a matrix $R =\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix} \in SO(2)$ and re-imagine it as 
$$
R =\begin{pmatrix} a & b & 0\\ c & d & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
You can easily show that all such $3\times 3$ matrices gives a subgroup of $SO(3)$ which is isomorphic in every way to $SO(2)$.  Hence we may regard this copy of $SO(2)$ as a subgroup of $SO(3)$ and then take its cosets.

Comment: Wow, wonderful! Thank you very much!